# Rails + Ec2 + multiple environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I am ROR developer and I am getting one issue. Please read the details below about issue.

I have deployed my Rails application on Ec2 server and I am managing 3 environment (staging, testing, production) on single Ec2 instance and I am using nginx + passenger server. 
I am using those environment via port number. for example 
staging url: http://ec2ipaddress:8080/users/sign_in
testing url: http://ec2ipaddress:5000/users/sign_in

now what issue I am getting suppose I am running my application(in staging environment) on any browser then after few hours it says like refused connection and it does not display anything in browser. and then if I change port number from 8080 to 5000 and hit then it works and again revert my port number 5000 to 8080 then it works fine.

I have checked the server logs and when it block then no request comes on server.

if anybody know please help me.

Regards,
R.K.

Comment: Now I have deleted multiple environments and only using single environment (Production environment) so today I run application for 2 hours and after 2 hours it seems like blocked and no request is coming on server when I am refreshing the page.

but when I deleted browser cache then it is working fine. 
and after some time this thing happened again.

Please help me.